# Can't enter in WINDOWS 10 after SYSPREP: INVALID ANSWER FILE

Tags: windows-10

I'm in a mess.

I made my golden image with OS WINDOWS 10 PRO (32 bit) in AUDIT mode. Every thing was perfect: user programs, shortcuts, apps, group policy settings etc. etc.
It was originally made on a 1709 version and then recently updated to the 1803 version.

I used an answer file: it came originally from an 64 bit version (we have old computers ...).

The only thing I changed in the answer file was the processorArchitecture: **amd64** to **x86** in all the posts. (Maybe I was too lazy ...?)

I ran the sysprep /generalize /shutdown etc. with this attend file.

When I restarted the computer to finalize the installation (eventually on a cloned computer or - now - the original computer) I got a message that the answer file is invalid and I just have to press the [OK] bottom.
When doing so the computer reboots. And I now get a new message:

**INSTALL WINDOWS:** *The computer restarted unexpectedly or encounted an unexpected error. ....*

I'm asked to press the bottom and restart the installation.
I've tried to reboot again in the AUDIT mode - [CTRL][SHIFT][F3] or just without anything. Always with the same remark: Restart installation.

I'm I lost and have to redo a new image ... ? Or is there a tweak to get into the good old AUDIT mode, before I syspreped the machine.

Comment: I always backup the image before I sysprep it because sysprep is such a mine field.

Comment: My initial though would be: Well, recreate the image with the correct settings on the PC which you mae it on, and then try to apply it again to the other PC. But since you posted this I guess both are the same and you did not keep a backup elsewhere. Sadly I cannot solve that. What I can do is explain what went wrong:

"amd_64" is for 64 bits components (the 64 bit standard from AMD, used by both AMD and Intel). "x86" is only for 32bits.

Comment: And in order to change windows from 64 bit to 64 bit or vice versa one does a complete new install. As in, there is no simple flag to set to say 'now switch to from 32 bit to 64 bit mode or vice versa.  You either boot 32 bit and install 32 bit, or boot 64 and it installs the normal 64bit version.    If you do try to swap without that problem occur (as you sadly noticed).

Comment: The only two workarounds which I would know that works atm is 1a) rescue all data (or have up to date tested backups). Disk in external drive dock, or a live CD work here. 1b) Wipe the old OS (usually found on C:).  1c) Do a clean installation 1d) restore backup.  and 2) boot your rescue pendrive/CD and restore from last backup. But that assumes that you have an up to date backup.

Comment: @Hennes. Sorry for my late response. I finally did a totally new install and made a new answer file from the ground - no shortcuts. And it's working. The only thing I've 'learned' for good, is to save a copy of the OS in AUDIT mode. And it is of course from here I can add programs or do whatever changes before sysprepping.